# How do I submit multiple forms to a php page where the number of forms generated is random?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a code that populates input fields at the final step according to a specified number (ranging from 1 to 6) per choice. The user can make 4 choices at maximum which potentially brings to 24 input fields or 4 forms.

This means that every choice will have at max 6 input fields i.e 4 different forms.

I want to submit these forms onto a PHP page where the inputs will then be sorted and inserted into a mySQl database accordingly. Now, I obviously cannot submit these forms using POST since one form POST will override the other.

It has to be AJAX (or that's what I think). The problem is the random serialization of the forms. Since the user has the option to select 4 (or less) forms to input, how do I generate a script for AJAX to understand how many forms are there in a page and then submit them one by one?

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){   //Count total number of products in cart
$total          = 0;
$count          =1;
$member_count   =1;
$list_tax       = '';
$cart_box       = '<ul class="view-cart">';

foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){ //Print each item, quantity and price.
    $event_name = $product["event_name"];
    $event_price = $product["event_price"];
    $event_code = $product["event_code"];
    $total_members=$product["total_members"];
    $item_price     = sprintf("%01.2f",($event_price));  // price x qty = total item price

    $cart_box       .="<form name=\"form$count\" action=\"pay.php\" method=\"POST\" id=\"$event_code\">"; //Generate one form per product
    $cart_box       .=  "<li> $event_code &ndash;  $event_name <span> $currency $item_price </span></li>";

    $total      = ($total+$event_price); //Multiply item quantity * price
for($i=0;$i<$total_members-1;$i++){

    $cart_box  .="<input name=\"member$member_count\" type=\"text\"></input> //Input fields per form




    <br/><br/>";
    $member_count++;
}
$cart_box       .="</form>";
$count++;


}


$grand_total = $total; //grand total




$cart_box .= "<li class=\"view-cart-total\">Payable Amount : $currency ".sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total)."</li>";
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){

    $cart_box .="<button class=\"w3-btn w3-red w3-right\" type=\"submit\" onclick=\"submitHere()\" >Pay</button> //Pay only if user logged in
    <script>function submitHere(){

        document.forms['cl_01'].submit();
    };</script>"


    ;




}
else{
        $cart_box .="Login";

}
$cart_box .= "</ul>";

echo $cart_box;
}else{
echo "Your Cart is empty";
}
?>
```

tl;dr: A cart page that randomly generates forms upto a maximum of 4 with each form containing a maximum of 6 input fields which have to be submitted onto a PHP page. We have no way of knowing how many forms will be generated at a time.

[A sample output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LElZM.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to identifier the forms separately. Such like `form_{product_name}_{category_name}` This way you can specify the form as well as input types.

secondly, PHP form handler can't handle multiple forms in each request.

So, you need to hack the code such like identify each form with hidden input type field i.g, `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="{value_for_form_idenfier}">`

Comment: I really wanted to avoid the hidden input fields, tbh. Is there some cleaner way to do this?